# How to turn off the beep sound when pressing volume up/down buttons on Lenovo s660?

Tags: audio, volume-control, custom-sounds

Here is the sound on YouTube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-H5ZOVelLEw

*The sound video was uploaded by a person who has the same problem as me, though he has a smartphone of another model. In general, there are not few people asking the question but the solution still has not been found. I would like to place the links to the people's questions but I don't have enough reputation to put more than 2 links here.*

I checked the /system folder and **/system/media/audio/ui** folder particularly and found the sound fallbackring.ogg only in the latter. But this is not the sound produced by the volume buttons (as I have learnt it is an input call sound playing when the Bluetooth is turned on and used).

Then I have found the page [http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2378177](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2378177) where the screen unlock system sound is replaced. The sound is situated in **/system/framework/framework-res.apk**. So I copied the framework-res.apk file and all the .apk files from /system/priv-app (as in the folder there are .apk files whose names sound like system: SystemUI.apk, Settings.apk, IputDevices.apk and etc. on my smartphone) to my PC, converted them to ZIP and searched there for any .ogg, .mp3 and .wav files. I have found some .ogg and .mp3 system sounds but not the volume button system sound and I have also found files like open.wav, open_bluetooth.wav, success.wav and failure.wav but I managed to play them with VLC media player neither on Windows nor on Linux and, still, their names have nothing in common with the volume button.

So here is my small investigation. Could someone, please, give me a tip where the annoying beep sound can be kept? Or, maybe, is it produced with hardware of the smartphone? I will appreciate any help.

Comment: If your phone is **rooted** and installed **Xposed**, you can try the '**GravityBox**' module, which has an option to **"Mute Volume Adjust Sound"**

Comment: @GokulNC, thank you very much for your comment. I will try to install Xposed and GravityBox. I've never used the module before though I've heard of it. Hope I will manage it.

Comment: @beeshyams, thank you. Yes, I want to get rid of the beep sound by any means. For example, I have a sound file "silence.ogg" that is just a second length silence and I was going to replace the beep sound .ogg file with the silence file if I could only find the location of the beep file.

Answer (score 0):

Just some clarification, the tone is not a media file that's played. It all done programmability as seen here: https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_frameworks_base/commit/3c786740240d8cc3b7615e36b6fad698bf79a825

After looking at your device, you probably won't be installing Xposed & Gravity Box as I couldn't even find TWRP available for the S660. Upload your SystemUI.apk and I'll have a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

If it's not a configurable setting through the frontend userspace, you may still be able to find it under your device's settings.db files.  In order to access and edit these, you'll need to use an application such as [SetEdit](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=by4a.setedit22).  Note that you may need to grant SetEdit some permission via ADB (the app description in Play Market tells you which ones) before you can edit values within certain tables.

Individual volume levels should all be listed towards the bottom of the System table; however, if you can't find it among the entries there, it's still possible that it's located elsewhere, so expect to comb through the tables if that becomes the case.

Comment: Please don't post generic answers. How do you expect OP to know what table key they need to fix the problem? SetEdit is a tool to change table key values. But to use that the table and key needs to be known beforehand. You have not addressed the crucial "how to figure out the key" part.

Comment: I specified "towards the bottom of the System table" because that's where all the "volume" key values are located (at least on my own devices).  In order to find out the *exact* key value, I would need to have the subject device model available to test, which I do not have on hand; furthermore, these key values aren't typically something you can look up through a search engine (I've tried).

Comment: The key values themselves are not obfuscated, and in most cases, they are human-readable and their functions are mostly pretty simple to infer based upon the key names and values themselves.  @Firelord